# How does MediaWiki calculate the file path to an image?

Tags: image, mediawiki

I'm just installing MediaWiki (loving it). I'm lookin at [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Images) for adding images. I can se the logic of

> [[File:MediaWiki:Image sample|50px]]

but where so I set the filepath for "File" (nothing obvious in LocalSettings.php) ... or is there some other logic at work?

I'd appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: If the image button inserts `[[File:MediaWiki:Image sample|50px]]` there must be some trouble with the translation. `MediaWiki:Image sample` is the name of the wiki page from where the sample file name should be taken.

Answer (score 11):

File location is determined by [$wgLocalFileRepo](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLocalFileRepo) which by default depends on [$wgUploadDirectory](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUploadDirectory) and [$wgHashedUploadDirectory](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHashedUploadDirectory). The upload directory defaults to `[MediaWiki base dir]/images` (Adrian must be using an older version). [If hashing is enabled](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHashedUploadDirectory), `/x/xy` will be appended to the path, where xy are the first two letters of the md5 hash of the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The defaults from DefaultSettings.php are:

$wgUploadPath       = "$wgScriptPath/uploads";
$wgUploadDirectory  = "$IP/uploads";

If you want to change this, you should copy and paste this into [LocalSettings.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php#Image_uploads)

And make sure that `$wgEnableUploads       = true;` is in LocalSettings.php too.

Comment: This does not seem to be accurate (any more). $wgUploadPath defaults to {$wgScriptPath}/images, and $wgUploadDirectory to {$IP}/images.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Image sample" is the name of image, not the name of a file. By config file you can just set the root folder for image uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference in case someone else runs into this issue:

I installed MediaWiki on my Mac OS Sierra and when I attempted to upload an image I got the following message:

```
Failed:
Could not open lock file for "mwstore://local-backend/local-public/d/d9/babypicture.png".
```

I changed the permissions on the mediawiki_root/images folder to be owned by _www user and group.

```
chown -R _www:_www wiki/images
```

I was able to upload the image afterward.