# How to find image path in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like find the exact URL for an image in mediawiki to send in my pinterest code. 
To find the page URL I use urlencode($wgTitle->getFullURL()) but I can't figure out what code to use for image and image description. 
Thanks

Comment: Posting as a comment since this is not a *programming* solution and may therefore not be relevant: e.g. on Wikipedia there is article entitled [Subspecies of Galápagos tortoise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspecies_of_Gal%C3%A1pagos_tortoise). If you click on the [tortoise image you go to this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lonesome_George_-Pinta_giant_tortoise_-Santa_Cruz.jpg). Clicking now on the [tortoise image takes you to the image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Lonesome_George_-Pinta_giant_tortoise_-Santa_Cruz.jpg) with the URL displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

To get the filepath in a wiki page, you can use [`[[Special:Filepath]]`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Filepath), the [`{{filepath:...}}` parser function](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#URL_data) or a link to the [`Media` namespace](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Namespaces#Media).

To get it programmatically with PHP, you might want to have a look at [How does MediaWiki calculate the file path to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2813294/1048572) or the [code of the filepath function](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/core.git;a=blob;f=includes/parser/CoreParserFunctions.php;hb=HEAD#l756):

```
$file = wfFindFile( $filename );
$url = $file->getFullUrl();
```

([`getFullUrl()` method](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classFile.html#af8c5eb22ef823da22ef335f2fdb11e30) in the `File` class)

For your use case you might also have a look at the [Extension:AddThis](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AddThis), they plan to support Pinterest too.

Comment: How would I use this with pinterest. When I click the 'pin it' button I want it to take an image from the page. I can't manually put in the filename of the image? Is there a global to get the filename?

Comment: Which environment do you have? Is there an extension that adds JavaScript pinterest buttons?

Comment: I got the code from http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/ but they only give a code for a specific page and image. I need it to work on with every page and image.

Comment: OK, that means you could even use a custom version of http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js. Where in your MediaWiki code do you generate the links? Is it only for image description pages?

Comment: I have the code in the skin file. So far I have   
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' . urlencode($wgTitle->getFullURL()) . '&media= &description== &is_video= class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"><img border="0" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a> I'm not sure how to code the media=, description= and video= so it takes an image from the page.

Comment: I guess you need to go some levels deeper. I'd try to add it somewhere to file page output.

Answer (score 1):

```
$f = wfFindFile( 'Foo.jpg' );
$imageUrl = $f->getCanonicalUrl(); // http://mywiki.com/images/0/06/Foo.jpg
$descriptionPage = $f->getTitle()->getFullUrl(); // http://mywiki.com/wiki/File.jpg
```

See the [File](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classFile.html) class and [Title](http://svn.wikimedia.org/doc/classTitle.html) class docs for details.

Comment: descriptionPage doesn't give me the description of the image. I need the text 'sunset over the beach' from File:sunset.jpg|Sunset over the beach, not a url. How do I find the code for this?

Comment: @LTech: In which context? E.g. just from wikitext of a random page or you need it when extending parser?

Comment: Thanks for your code, It is really helpful. The problem I have is the first line - $f = wfFindFile( 'Foo.jpg' ); I can't manually put in the file name, how do I get the file name of an image on the page using php. There is __get($name) but I'm not sure how to use it. Would you know? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can link to the page `/wiki/Special:Filepath/File_name` or `/wiki/Special:Redirect/file/File_name`, that will redirect the request to the full image location, for example: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Filepath/**Turtle.jpg**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Filepath/Turtle.jpg) redirects to the full image path [https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/**Turtle.jpg**](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Turtle.jpg)