# Python equivalent to PHP's getCanonicalURL

Tags: python, python-3.x

In PHP, there is supposedly some code -- a function called `getCanonicalUrl` -- that returns the url of a file

```
$f = wfFindFile( 'Foo.jpg' );
$imageUrl = $f->getCanonicalUrl(); // http://mywiki.com/images/0/06/Foo.jpg
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205314/4262207

Does python3 have an equivalent to this method?

Comment: Not directly.  PHP always assumes it is part of a web page, so it always has a base URL.  Python does not.  What web framework are you using?  It may have such a function.

Comment: "there is supposedly some code" - Is there code or just "supposedly"? I've found vague references to things inside of MediaWiki, maybe you could start there?

Comment: What about https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath Then, if you want its path relative to some docroot you may have to remove the docroot yourself.